# OpenVPN Server not allowing clients to ping or connect to any websites

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, openvpn, vpn

I am actually using Windows on the client, but the server is Linux and that's where I believe the problem to be.

I recently set up a VPN service on my VPS (Ubuntu 18.04) according to Digital Oceans guide (How To Set Up an OpenVPN Server on Ubuntu 18.04)

I used the same server for both the CA and the VPN server, so the certificates are on a server which is online (not recommended by the author)

I have the log file for the OpenVPN client

It successfully connected but I cannot ping Google when I connect using the OpenVPN client on Windows 10, and cannot connect to
Google or anybody else through Firefox

Here is the log file from OpenVPN

https://pastebin.com/4eTja2zg

Here is the server configuration file

https://pastebin.com/khJLJ6LA

I have attached a screenshot of the log files on the Linux VPS[image]

Any help is very much appreciated, can tip in XLM :)

Comment: Take a look at the OpenVPN log. It tries to create routes using `route.exe`, do the IPs listed there seem sensible (matching your network)? Also, please explain what "cannot connect" means (do you get an error? Which one?)

Comment: I just updated the OpenVPN log (before it was the log after I had manually disconnected)

Cannot connect means I get "request timed out" when I ping Google

Comment: Ok so it turns out that I can actually stay connected on an SSH session even when my traffic is routed through the VPN... But I can't connect to Google. Hmm

Comment: Did you set the masquerade on your server?